# self.tabBarController.selectedViewController thrown off by uinavigationController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a single view application containing a tabBarController, a navigationController, and two views (xcode 4.2).  I want to identify when a given tab has been selected, and planned on doing so using the following code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSLog(@"in testtableView.  %@", self.tabBarController.selectedViewController);
    NSLog(@"in testtableView. tab bar index is: %i", self.tabBarController.selectedIndex);

}
```

this code is included in both views.  It works perfectly when the navigationController is not there, ie, when the application is a simple tabbed application.  But when the navigationController is included, it causes the indexes to "slip" by one the first time the second tab (the navigationController) is selected, but not there-after if the user decides to continue switching between the tabs.

Here are two screen-shots:
[screen shots http://s1305.photobucket.com/user/michael_jensen2/media/Screenshot2013-04-07at50743PM_zps1fab25ab.png.html?evt=email_share](http://s1305.photobucket.com/user/michael_jensen2/media/Screenshot2013-04-07at50743PM_zps1fab25ab.png.html?evt=email_share).
I tried putting them on photobucket..  any better way of doing it?  Here is the output, calling each of the functions in different tests:

```
2013-04-07 17:21:31.728 testTabBar[1921:207] in firstViewController.  <tabBarTestFirstViewController: 0x684ea80>
2013-04-07 17:21:53.626 testTabBar[1921:207] in secondViewConroller.  <UINavigationController: 0x684fce0>
2013-04-07 17:22:04.528 testTabBar[1921:207] in firstViewController.  <UINavigationController: 0x684fce0>
2013-04-07 17:22:06.544 testTabBar[1921:207] in secondViewConroller.  <tabBarTestFirstViewController: 0x684ea80>
2013-04-07 17:22:07.392 testTabBar[1921:207] in firstViewController.  <UINavigationController: 0x684fce0>
2013-04-07 17:22:07.816 testTabBar[1921:207] in secondViewConroller.  <tabBarTestFirstViewController: 0x684ea80>
2013-04-07 17:22:08.288 testTabBar[1921:207] in firstViewController.  <UINavigationController: 0x684fce0>
```

.

```
2013-04-07 17:50:33.075 testTabBar[2066:207] in firstViewController. tab bar index is: 0
2013-04-07 17:50:37.526 testTabBar[2066:207] in secondViewConroller. tab bar index is: 1
2013-04-07 17:50:37.982 testTabBar[2066:207] in firstViewController. tab bar index is: 1
2013-04-07 17:50:38.301 testTabBar[2066:207] in secondViewConroller. tab bar index is: 0
2013-04-07 17:50:38.668 testTabBar[2066:207] in firstViewController. tab bar index is: 1
2013-04-07 17:50:39.100 testTabBar[2066:207] in secondViewConroller. tab bar index is: 0
2013-04-07 17:50:39.532 testTabBar[2066:207] in firstViewController. tab bar index is: 1
2013-04-07 17:50:39.988 testTabBar[2066:207] in secondViewConroller. tab bar index is: 0
2013-04-07 17:50:40.372 testTabBar[2066:207] in firstViewController. tab bar index is: 1
```

any thoughts?  There may be a solution to this already posted, but I haven't found it yet.

-mike

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
{

    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) {




    }
    else if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1)
    {



    }

}
```